# Escriba una función que tome el carrito de compras como entrada y devuelva el diccionario correcto

Tags: python

Hola buenas tengo que realizar el siguiente ejercicio:
Escriba una función llamada most_spent_on_item que tome el carrito de compras como entrada y devuelva el diccionario asociado con el artículo que tiene el precio más alto * cantidad.

Nos dan esto:

```py
shopping_cart = {
    "tax": .08,
    "items": [
        {
            "title": "orange juice",
            "price": 3.99,
            "quantity": 1
        },
        {
            "title": "rice",
            "price": 1.99,
            "quantity": 3
        },
        {
            "title": "beans",
            "price": 0.99,
            "quantity": 3
        },
        {
            "title": "chili sauce",
            "price": 2.99,
            "quantity": 1
        },
        {
            "title": "chocolate",
            "price": 0.75,
            "quantity": 9
        }
    ]
}
```

Y yo he hecho esto:

```py
def most_spent_on_item(shopping_cart):
    total_spent = 0
    for item in shopping_cart["items"]:
        total_spent += item["price"]*item["quantity"] 
   #Y aqui ya no se como hacer para comparar el total spent de cada item y quedarme con el mayor 
   #para devolver ese diccionario     


assert most_spent_on_item(shopping_cart) == { #Esto es para comprobar que el ejercicio da el                                              
    "title": "chocolate",                     #resultado correcto
    "price": 0.75,
    "quantity": 9
}
```

Comment: Tu código obtiene el gasto total que hizo el dueño del carrito, eso no te servirá para obtener lo que buscas. Te serviría usar la función [max](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/python-max-function/) (si es que te permiten usarla)

Comment: Entiendo lo que me dices pero no se como hacer. Soy muy principiante en esto. Lo siento y muchas gracias

Comment: No pasa nada c: max puede ser un poco complejo. max acepta un primer argumento, que sería un iterable (lista, tupla, cadena, etc) y un argumento llamado key que acepta una función que devolverá por que comparar cada item. Por ejemplo si haces `max(("a", "bc", "def"), key=len)` la función len se aplica a cada item de la tupla y te devolverá la cadena más larga. Me llegaste a entender?

Comment: Creo entender que me devolvera "def" ya que es la cadena mas larga. Es asi?

Comment: Estás en lo correcto! Con ese conocimiento podrás avanzar?

Comment: Pero yo lo que quiero es obtener el item de la tupla que tenga mayor price*quantity. que en este caso es el chocolate. Entonces no veo la relación con la función max

Comment: Te daré una respuesta usando la función max, espero que puedas aprender de ello. Si la función max no está permitida, puedes usar la respuesta de Taehyung95.

Comment: Te lo agradecería ya que la intención es aprender. Un saludo

Answer (score 0):

A mi lo que se me ocurrió bastante sencillo es lo siguiente:

```
total_spent = 0
valor_real = 0
for item in shopping_cart["items"]:
    total_spent = item["price"]*item["quantity"] 
    if total_spent > valor_real:
       valor_real = total_spent
       diccionario_final = item
return diccionario_final
```

Lo que he añadido a tu código es una nueva variable para poder hacer la comparación de qué resultado de la multiplicación es mayor. Luego si se cumple que es mayor, dentro de la variable `diccionario_final` es donde se guardará el **item** que buscas y es lo que devolverá la función.

Cualquier duda me comentas.

Comment: Muchas Gracias compañero es una buena solución pero voy a esperar por la solución  de @Dante usando el método max() para entender como funciona y como usarla. Muchísimas gracias nuevamente

Comment: De nada!! Así tienes más opciones y ves varias formas de lograrlo @Samuel

Answer (score 0):

Para obtener lo que buscas puedes hacer lo siguiente:

```
def obtener_precio_por_cantidad(item_de_la_lista):
    return item_de_la_lista["price"]*item_de_la_lista["quantity"]

diccionario = max(shopping_cart["items"], key=obtener_precio_por_cantidad)
```

Donde shopping_cart["items"], como sabes, es la lista de items, y key es la función a  aplicar a cada item. El resultado de esta función se usará después para realizar comparaciones entre cada item.

Sin embargo, la función max puede ser dificil de entender y puede no estar permitida por el ejercicio. Así que para que puedas entender que hace max y que tengas una alternativa pondré un equivalente aquí.

```
def obtener_precio_por_cantidad(item_de_la_lista):
    return item_de_la_lista["price"]*item_de_la_lista["quantity"]

# Obtenemos el primer item de la lista. Esto es por que no tenemos nada con que comparar el primer item.
mayor_item = shopping_cart["items"][0]
# aplicamos al primer item de la lista la funcion obtener_precio_por_cantidad y lo guardamos en la variable mayor_valor. Pues por ahora ese es el mayor precio*cantidad
mayor_valor = obtener_precio_por_cantidad(mayor_item)

# Empesamos a iterar desde el segundo item de la lista, ya que ya trabajamos con el primero.
for item in shopping_cart["items"][1:]:

    # creamos una variable auxiliar que contiene el item actual procesado por la función obtener_precio_por_cantidad
    aux = obtener_precio_por_cantidad(item)

    # si el resultado de obtener_precio_por_cantidad(item) es mayor ultimo que vimos que era el más grande...
    if(aux > mayor_valor):
        # guardamos el nuevo mayor valor en su correspondiente variable
        mayor_valor = aux

        # y el mayor item pasa a ser el item visitado actualmente.
        mayor_item = item

print(mayor_item)
```

Posible escenario: No se si está planteado en el ejercicio. Pero que crees que pasaría si dos o más items tienen igual `price*quantity`?

Comment: Muy buena explicación compañero, no esta planteado ya que es un ejercicio cerrado, pero me imagino que si dos o mas items tiene el mismo price*quantity solo me devolverá el ultimo a no ser que me tire un error

Comment: Mis pruebas indican que si hay dos o más items con el mismo price*quantity te devuelve de todos esos que son iguales el primero que encontró. Tanto con max como con el equivalente que hice.

Comment: Y gracias, pongo mucho esfuerzo y tiempo en mis explicaciones c:

Comment: Ah ok yo no sabia si el que devolvía era el ultimo por que sobrescribía a los demás o el primero porque al comparar dice es igual y no lo sobrescribo. Pero si tenia claro que algo no haría bien.                                                      Un saludo y gracias nuevamente